# Reset a form in React and console log the details on the server side

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, react-hooks

1. How to reset a form after submitting it? Now after submitting the form, the details are still displayed in the form. At the moment the form is simply submitting to the server, without any connection to a database.
2. Also, is it possible to `console.log()` the submitted details on the server side? I have tried `console.log("Serverside printing:"+req.newstitle);`, but I am getting undefined.

[image]

server.js:

```
app.post('/service/news', (req, res) => {
  console.log("Serverside printing:"+req.newstitle);
  res.json({ express: "news" })
});
```

News.js:

```
const [newstitle, setNewsTitle]=useState([]);
  const [newsDetails, setNewsDetails]=useState([]);
  const [isSent, setIsSent] = useState(false);

  const successfullMessage = <p>Details submittted successfully !</p>
  const form = <form>...</form>

  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/service/news', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({ newstitle, newsDetails })
    }).then(() => setIsSent(true))
  }

  return(
          <div className="container">            
            <div className="layout">
              <span className="col col-main">
                <h3>What is so special about Us ?</h3>
                <span className="specialAboutus_data_1">
                  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="myForm">
                    <div className="loginfillContentDiv formElement">
                      <label>
                        <input name="newstitle"  className="inputRequest formContentElement" type="text" placeholder="Title" 
                        onChange={e => setNewsTitle(e.target.value)}/>
                      </label>
                      <label>
                        <textarea name="newsdetails" className="inputRequest formContentElement" type="textarea" placeholder="News details" 
                        onChange={e => setNewsDetails(e.target.value)}/>
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="loginsubmitButtonDiv formElement">
                        <button type="submit" className="submitButton">Save</button>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </span>
              </span> 
              <span className="col col-complementary">
              <h3>Are you keen to join us ? </h3>
              <span className="joinAboutus_data_1">
                 {isSent ? successfullMessage  : form }
              </span>  
              </span>  
            </div>     
          </div>
        )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why `newsDetails` and `newstitle` (I guess it should be `newsTitle`...?) are defined as `[]`. Doesn't a string makes more sense or am I missing something here?
Also you're missing the `value` attribute on your inputs, which should be set by the corresponding state variable, in order to sync the UI with the state.
To clear the form you can just call `setNewsDetails` and `setNewsTitle` with empty values e.g: `setNewsTitle([])` (or `setNewsTitle('')`).
Anyways here's a basic working example:

```
const App = () => {

  // console.log('works');
  const [newsTitle, setNewsTitle] = useState('');
  const [newsDetails, setNewsDetails] = useState('');
  const [isSent, setIsSent] = useState(false);

  const successfullMessage = <p>Details submittted successfully !</p>
  const form = <p>Form</p>

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('state: ', newsTitle, newsTitle);

    // fetch here

    setIsSent(true);

    // clear the form
    setNewsTitle('');
    setNewsDetails('');
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>hello!</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label>
            <input
              name="newstitle"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Title"
              value={newsTitle} // sync with state
              onChange={e => setNewsTitle(e.target.value)} 
            />
          </label>
          <label>
            <textarea
              name="newsdetails"
              placeholder="News details"
              value={newsDetails} // sync with state
              onChange={e => setNewsDetails(e.target.value)}
            />
          </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Save</button>
        </div>
      </form>
      {isSent ? successfullMessage : form}
    </div>
  ) 
}
```

As for the logging on the server, I think your missing the `body` property on the request:

```js
app.post('/service/news', (req, res) => {
  console.log("Serverside printing:" + req.body.newstitle);
  res.json({ express: "news" })
});
```